# If CloudSQL proxy is being used to connect to CloudSQL databases then why am I still getting the SHA alert SSL_NOT_ENFORCED?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, cloud-sql-proxy

I am trying to understand an alert from Google's Security Health Analytics - "SSL_NOT_ENFORCED"

This documentation - https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/sql-proxy states

> The Cloud SQL Proxy provides secure access to your instances without the need for Authorized networks or for configuring SSL.

therefore why is SSL_NOT_ENFORCED still being alerted on? Is this just frustrating alert logic?

Of course, I wouldn't want to disable this alert just incase there ever is a Cloud SQL Proxy where there really is no SSL enforced but I would like to determine whether or not i can consider some findings as false positives.

Answer (score 2):

The security center findings are there so you can understand and monitor your project's security stance. Only you can evaluate which of the findings are important to your organization. Only you can decide what actions to take to improve your security.

If you are very sure that all servers connecting to your SQL servers are private and all the connections to those servers are also private then you might be willing
to avoid the cost of SSL connections to your SQL servers.

Many security experts suggest defense in depth strategies where you deploy multiple
layers of security. In that case you would want all connections even those originating from internal servers to use  SSL connections.

As you can see in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/authorize-ssl), it’s recommended enforcing SSL/TLS connections when using public IPs, so the data is secure during transmission. If your data isn't encrypted, anyone can examine your packets and read confidential information. If for example, because of a vulnerability with any service in your network will let someone to penetrate it, this will also allow examining your packets in case you have a not encrypted connection, and that’s why the process and the recommendation are the same for private IPs. If you don’t enforce encryption connection, you will never be sure that all the internal communications are happening over https.

Since Cloud SQL can manage the certificates and SSL configuration for you the management cost for enforcing SSL connections is reduced. The performance hit is still there.